# Plastic Seat for Vintage Kids Tricycle

Tags: repair, saddle

Anybody can tell me where to find this type of plastic seat?
It sits directly on the tube, and holds on with a bolt on the middle.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Ask your local maker space to help make you on on their 3D printer.

Comment: @RoboKaren potentially yes, but printed plastic lacks the resiliency of molded stuff, so its generally a lot more brittle.   Possibly using a lightweight metal plate as the fastener interface and main pan, and then printing on that (somehow) could provide a better item.  3dprinting.SE anyone ?

Comment: You can print in ABS and seal it using an acetone vapor bath. Produces incredibly strong and smooth prints. I think the OP is looking for the "look" for a restoration rather than ridability anyway.

Comment: If someone came round to our bike rehab group looking for such a seat we MIGHT be able to find one, in exchange for a small donation.  (I don't see anything wrong with that one, though.  Why do you want to replace it?)